# Find a Structure member

Tags: excel, vba, find, structure, user-defined-types

I am trying to use the method "Find" to find (haha) a member of a structure type defined by me.

```
Public Type Repuesto
    Codigo As Integer
    Almacen As Integer
    EnMano As Integer
    EnOrden As Integer
End Type
```

I have created a structure array called "MisRepuestos", filling all the "Codigo" members. After that I tried to do this:

```
Cells.Find(What:=MisRepuestos_1(1).Codigo).Activate
```

So, here's when excel stops working and restarts... Any ideas about why this might be happening? I have already checked that the array members are actually filled with an integer by printing them.

Comment: That should work fine, is there additional code?  If so what happens if you create a new workbook and use what you have posted (and a dim) on its own?